# Add Multiple Datatable(Different Structure) Into Gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datatable

In My Program I Need To Merge(Copy Or Anything That'll Work) Two DataTables With Different Structures Into One And Make That As The GridView's DataSource.
First DataTable Will Always Have 1 Row To Be Added But Second DataTable Will Have Multiple Rows.
The Problem Is:When First DataTable's Row Added, It Will Be GridViews Datasource(To Show The User That Everything Is Fine) And User Starts To Insert Second Datatables Rows One By One And Each Time One Row Added To Second Datatable ,Gridview Must Refresh And Show New Rows(All Merged Together)
I Already Tried So Many Ways But All Of Them Had Some Problem!!
The Last Code I Tried Is This:

```
public partial class Main : Form1
{
    DataTable DT1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable DT2 = new DataTable();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DT1.Columns.Add("@number", typeof(int));
        DT1.Columns.Add("@name", typeof(string));
        DT1.Columns.Add("@date", typeof(string));
        DT1.Columns.Add("@tel", typeof(string));

        DT2.Columns.Add("@piece", typeof(string));
        DT2.Columns.Add("@descrip", typeof(string));
        DT2.Columns.Add("@accessories", typeof(string));
        DT2.Columns.Add("@damage", typeof(string));
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DT1.Rows.Add(T1.Text, T2.Text, T3.Text, T4.Text);
        DT2.Rows.Add(T5.Text, T6.Text, T7.Text, T8.Text);
        DT1.AcceptChanges();
        DT1.Merge(DT2);
        Gridview1.DataSource = DT1;
    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DT2.Rows.Add(T5.Text, T6.Text, T7.Text, T8.Text);
        DT1.Merge(DT2);
        Gridview1.DataSource = DT1;
    }
```

When The User Fills The Texts, Button1 Will Trigger
And Every Time The User Insert New Data In Texts, Button2 Will Trriger
Any suggestions Are Welcome

Comment: You only need to merge all data into one data table

Comment: This Happens:

http://picpaste.com/pics/1-A2bxhHAX.1493455436.jpg
Second DataTables Row, Repeated!